# How customisable is the Parse.com iOS login/ signup screen?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've been doing some research, and all I can find is ways to add and remove `fields and buttons`, as well as to skin the app. I would like to change the position and size of certain `buttons and fields`. I just cannot seem to see how to do so.

Is this possible at all? Are there any alternatives, perhaps such as creating your own `signup/login screen`, while still being able to securely send a username and password to `parse.com` to create a user object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Seems Parse have removed their tutorial instead of updating it. I would suggest some of these guides instead:

http://www.appcoda.com/login-signup-parse-swift/
or
https://www.codementor.io/swift/tutorial/adding-twitter-facebook-login-parse-tutorial-ios

**Old answer**
Parse.com have a dedicated tutorial for customizing the signup and login:

https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

Answer (score 0):

The parse documentation shows how to create your own login screen using the PFUser methods for logging in with FB, Twitter and username/password.

Comment: So, you're saying I'll be able to build my own login and signup screens using methods from ---> http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html ?